# Sequence for the instance variable in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the Rails view users/index.html.erb
I iterated over each users to list them all.
Want sequence no. in front of the user list. I have used `each_with_index` to achieve this.
I want to know if rails provides any better alternate to this. I am using rails 4.1

```
<% @users.each_with_index do |user,count| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= count+1 -%></td>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
```

Comment: If you don't want to write `count + 1`, then do `@users.each.with_index(1)` .. I don't know any more advance things is there or not..

Comment: I think so this is the only solution and how much you want to optimize it?